# How to create a loop for columns with (yyyy-mm-dd) format?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Abstracts:
I have two tables, one with the returns of the stocks and another with each respective quintile, I want to compute the average of the top quintile and the bottom one, therefore I used a left join function but still can't go further because my loop does not work.

Table one (returns) small sample (121 columns)
[image]

Table two (quintile) small sample (121 columns)
[image]

Code used:

```
                DECLARE  @CDate as date, @SQL as varchar (max)


                SET @CDate =  '2006-12-30' -- dates as string must be yyyy-mm-dd

                WHILE @CDate < '2016-12-31'
                       BEGIN


                           SET @SQL = 'SELECT AVG(MR.[' & @CDATE & ']) From MOMENTUM_Quintile MQ Left Join MOMENTUM_Returns MR on MQ.Mnemonic = MR.Mnemonic WHERE MQ.[' & @CDATE & '] = 1'



                           SET @CDate = DATEADD(mm, 1, @CDate) 
                           WHILE Month(@CDate) = Month(DATEADD(dd, 1, @CDate))
                                 BEGIN
                                   SET @CDate = DATEADD(dd, 1, @CDate)
                                 END
                        END
```

Error message:

```
                  Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
                  The data types varchar and date are incompatible in the '&' operator.
```

Here is a small sample table in which you can try the code for:

```
            CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MOMENTUM_Money](

              [MNEMONIC] [varchar](50) NULL,

              [2006-12-30] [money] NULL,

              [2007-01-30] [money] NULL,

              [2007-02-28] [money] NULL,

              [2007-03-30] [money] NULL,

              [2007-04-30] [money] NULL,

              [2007-05-30] [money] NULL,

              [2007-06-30] [money] NULL

              ) ON [PRIMARY]

        GO


                INSERT INTO momentum_returns (MNEMONIC,[2006-12-30],  [2007-01-30], [2007-02-28],  [2007-03-30],  [2007-04-30],  [2007-05-30], [2007-06-30])

                VALUES ('AAL', 510.1708, 489.0758, 494.8104, 557.2972, 555.6318, 606.8441, 613.0896),

                VALUES ('ABF',-6.5341   -6.4193 -6.5301 -6.8388 -7.3335 -7.385  -7.0781),

               VALUES ('ACB', 6.9713,   6.578,  6.559,  7.2885, 6.9103, 6.3598, 5.7575),

               VALUES ('ABC', 1.4600, 1.5030, 1.5352, 1.5609, 1.5447, 1.5609,   1.7493);
```

Therefore looking for a good insight to find how could I loop through these columns using the function I created. Thank you

Comment: In the `SET @SQL = ... & @cDATE & ...`, try changing the `&` to  `+`.

Comment: Sends the same message..

Comment: Why do you have dates as columns? These should be rows with a date column. When your design is denormalized it makes queries a LOT harder.

Comment: *[Please, type `DAY` instead of saving a whole 1 character](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @CDate AS DATE, @SQL AS VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @CDate = '2006-12-30'; -- dates as string must be yyyy-mm-dd
    WHILE @CDate < '2016-12-31'
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'This';
            SET @SQL = 'SELECT AVG(MR.['+CAST(@CDATE AS NVARCHAR(MAX))+']) 
                          From MOMENTUM_Quintile MQ 
                          Left Join MOMENTUM_Returns MR on MQ.Mnemonic = MR.Mnemonic 
                          WHERE MQ.['+CAST(@CDATE AS NVARCHAR(MAX))+'] = 1';        
            SET @CDate = DATEADD(mm, 1, @CDate);
            WHILE MONTH(@CDate) = MONTH(DATEADD(dd, 1, @CDate))
                BEGIN
                    SET @CDate = DATEADD(dd, 1, @CDate);
                END;
        END;
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this?

```
DECLARE  @CDate as date, @SQL as varchar (max), @cDateString nvarchar(20)


SET @CDate =  '2006-12-30' -- dates as string must be yyyy-mm-dd

WHILE @CDate < '2016-12-31'
       BEGIN

           SET @cDateString = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4),YEAR(@cDate)) + N'-' + FORMAT(MONTH(@cDate),'d2') + N'-' +FORMAT(DAY(@cDate),'d2')
           SET @SQL = 'SELECT AVG(MR.[' + @cDateString + ']) From MOMENTUM_Quintile MQ Left Join MOMENTUM_Returns MR on MQ.Mnemonic = MR.Mnemonic WHERE MQ.[' + @cDateString + '] = 1'



           SET @CDate = DATEADD(mm, 1, @CDate) 
           WHILE Month(@CDate) = Month(DATEADD(dd, 1, @CDate))
                 BEGIN
                   SET @CDate = DATEADD(dd, 1, @CDate)
                 END
        END
```